# How can I access a server if private key is lost

Tags: ssh, private-key, public-key

My hard disk was broken so I've lost my private key. I still have the public key though and I know the passphrase for the private key.

I want to access a server which had my public key in the authorized keys. I tried to login using ssh:

```
ssh debian@[server_ip]
```

but then it asks me for a password. I gave the passphrase but I get

> "Permission denied, please try again."

Is there a way to access the server again?

Comment: no... lost the key means you can never gain access .. That is the whole point of ssh auth

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/401068/lost-ssh-key-is-it-possible-to-log-in-via-some-other-method-now

Comment: This is possible if you have DigitalOcean: https://support.lamassu.is/hc/en-us/articles/115001695785-Recovering-from-a-lost-SSH-key

Answer (score 4):

Either you should have physical access to the server Or should ask admin to enable password access for you.
Or If its VPS you can generate new pair using web panel of platform provider. 
If you lost the keys means you need to have another method to access and there is always a way for you to get access if you are genuine user of that system.

Hope it helps